# `node` api getting error on `post` - body param being as labels how to solve this?

Tags: angularjs

I am posting the data to back-end using postman, which works fine. Using the same api I am trying to post the data through angular gives me the issue. But I understand that something going on wrongly between my `form` data with `post` process which i am not able to understand.

here is the post function:

```
.post(function( req, res ){

                console.log(' called ', req.body ); 1. //getting all properties

                var family = new Family();

                family.username = req.body.username,
                family.password = req.body.password,
                family.familyLeader = req.body.familyLeader,
                family.husband = req.body.husband,
                family.wife = req.body.wife,
                family.kids = req.body.kids;

                console.log( 'family username', req.body.username ); 2.//undefined? not getting

                family.save(function( err, newFamily ) {

                    if( err ) {

                        if ( err.code == 11000) {
                            return res.json({ success: false, message: 'A user with that username already exists. '});
                        }
                        else {
                            return res.send( err );
                        }

                    }

                    res.json({ message: 'Family created!', newFamily: newFamily });

                });


            })
```

There is 2 console I have in above call, in the first console I am getting the properties like this: ( I guess here is the issue, properties being as lable!? )

```
called  { '{"username":"arif","password":"sadfdsa","familyLeader":"sadffsa","husband":"sadfsad","wife":"sadfsad","kids":2}': '' }
```

and the next console give the value like this:

```
family username undefined
```

Comment: why is ur `req.body` printed as key value?

Comment: that's what I am confused. the angualar `$http` not sending the data as per expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed header from `$http` request, and it works fine.

my code with issue is : with header

```
vm.createNewFamily = function() {

            $http({
                method  : 'POST',
                url     : '/api/family',
                data    : vm.form,
                headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).success( function ( data ) {

                console.log('retured!', data );

            })

        }
```

and the solution is : ( header removed )

```
vm.createNewFamily = function() {

            $http({
                method  : 'POST',
                url     : '/api/family',
                data    : vm.form

                }).success( function ( data ) {

                console.log('retured!', data );

            })

        }
```

Experts - Please confirm the solution!